# Can garage and porch lights be on the same switch?

Tags: electrical

I am looking through electrical code trying to find out what the requirements are for light switches and switching on porch as well as garage lights when they are all on the front of the house? I would like to just have one switch to control the lights I am installing in the soffit in front of the garage and porch, and have that switch located by the front door as well as the interior mudroom door.  Is there any electrical code in terms of locating the switch the control those lights?  I know there is code about locating lights near any exterior doors, but I'm not finding anything about the switch location.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can put your exterior lights on one circuit as long as the draw from all of the lights combined does not exceed the ampacity rating of the breaker. Pretty common to have all exterior lights on a single switch (timer). The NEC doesn't care where you put the switch. You could install it in the bedroom closet if you wanted to (but I don't recommend it)

Comment: You might consider running separate cables to the different lights and joining them in parallel inside the switch box -- in case some future occupant wants to put some of the lights on separate switches.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.